# Cannot drag and drop from nautilus to Chrome or Slack

Tags: nautilus, google-chrome, slack

I am on a brand new install of Ubuntu 22.04.

I have chrome installed from deb and slack installed from snap.

When I try to drag a file from nautilus into either of these applications it does not work. This did work fine for me in 21.10.

Is there some way I can restore this behaviour in 22.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 runs on Wayland by default. In Wayland, with its focus on security, applications do not know of each other. One of the side effects is that drag and drop between applications is broken.

To restore the behavior of 21.10, log in to a session on Xorg. On the login screen, before entering your password, you can click the cog wheel on the bottom right and select "Ubuntu on Xorg" there.

Comment: reverting to Xorg feels like a bit of an unsatisfactory and retrograde choice. But drag and drop lacking is somewhat a daily nuisance.

Comment: This cog wheel only exists in *upgraded* installations. Clean/new installs of 22.04 do not have the cog wheel.

Comment: @JDS they have if the system supports both Wayland and Xorg.

Comment: Amazing! This solved another problem I had which I didn't know was related.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here with the OP's problem: Make sure that you use the deb package for Chrome. I had Chrome via flatpack which can lead to the same symptoms. But in my case the solution was simply to replace the flatpack version with the deb version.

Comment: https://github.com/flathub/com.google.Chrome/issues/267

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue/feature with Ubuntu 22.04.

Opening folders with `sudo nautilus /home/user/` or `sudo xdg-open /home/user/` fixes this.